# How to split diffent row length list column value in R

Tags: r

Help me how to split list column values into new data frame Single column value  in R programming language.

```
ID   AuIndex                                                                                               USER         

1   list(ParentID =c("1011","ZIP"),ChildID=c("765","Valuableuser"))                                             1

2   list(ParentID =c("4002","Dispatch","Paid"),ChildID=c("78678","User"))                                       1  

3   list(ParentID =c("76579","Arrival"),ChildID =c("5345","Low","High"))                                        1

4   list(ParentID =c("29920","Shipped","Ontheway"),ChildID =c("3453","Medium"),SuperChild=c("3534","Budged"))   1
```

O/P Data frame.

```
ID  AutoIndex.ParentID          AutoIndex.ChildID         AutoIndex.SuperChild     USER

1   "1011","ZIP"                 "765","Valuableuser"         NULL                  1

2   "4002","Dispatch","Paid"     "78678","User"               NULL                   1

3   "76579","Arrival"            "5345","Low","High"          NULL                   1

4  "29920","Shipped","Ontheway"   "3453","Medium"           "3534","Budged"          1
```

dput DATA.

```
structure(list(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), AutoupdateDetails = list(
    structure(list(ParentID = c("1011", "ZIP"), ChildID = c("765", 
    "Valuableuser")), .Names = c("ParentID", "ChildID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), 
    structure(list(ParentID = c("4002", "Dispatch", "Paid"), 
        ChildID = c("78678", "USER")), .Names = c("ParentID", 
    "ChildID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), structure(list(
        ParentID = c("76579", "Arrival"), ChildID = c("5345", 
        "Low", "High")), .Names = c("ParentID", "ChildID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), 
    structure(list(ParentID = c("29920", "Shipped", "Ontheway"
    ), ChildID = c("3453", "Medium"), SuperChild = c("3534", 
    "Budged")), .Names = c("ParentID", "ChildID", "SuperChild"
    ), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)), USER = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1")), .Names = c("ID", "AutoupdateDetails", "USER"
), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This data is super messed-up; it's defining data frames where the variables have different lengths. Fixing that upstream is the best option.

Comment: I don't think so this is duplicate .Because data frame list variable are different and row by row length also different ..@r2evans.

Comment: i  applied your posted page  code but i'm getting Error. ..@r2evans